# Is it possible to encode a PDF file in a JSON with PHP and then return it with AJAX? How?

Tags: php, ajax, pdf, backend

I hope you're fine

You'll see, I'm facing an issue that I'm not sure if even is possible to do

I'm working in a project which PHP backend is already configure to call the methods based on defined routes, like:

```
http://backend/app1/operation1
```

The backend could only receive parameters in JSON and it will return always a JSON with the result (I use AJAX for this)

This will call the operation1 functionality and it will return the JSON with the result

The thing is, one of the modules of the website has to show PDF files, be able to see it or download it

I haven't found any way to return PDF files in a JSON... not sure if possible to encode them and then decode them for re-create them or something like that

And since every time I point to the server the backend will re-enroute me, I can not download directly from their location

**Note:** I can not modify backend current configuration (the always JSON in and out)

Thanks in advance, I hope you could help me

Comment: Seems like a very poor setup if it doesn't allow you to return the data you need in the format that makes sense. You could base64 encode the file and add it as a value in the JSON response. Then you can decode it in JS to get it as a proper PDF again. However, base64 encoded data always gets larger than the original, so it's not optimal. You will also need to create the download using JS by opening a new window, adding all needed download headers and the PDF content. It should work, but is also not really optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it is not a good option, detail @M. Eriksson already explained.

if you want, check it out:

```
// PHP code
$binaryData = file_get_contents('./path/to/file.pdf');
$base64String = base64_encode($binaryData);
$response = array( 'status'=> true, 'pdfData' => $base64String);
echo json_encode($response);
```

For the javascript part

```
<a id="saveBtn">Save pdf</a>
<script>
    var pdfBase64String = ajaxResponse['pdfData'];
    var btn = document.getElementById('saveBtn');
    btn.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdfBase64String);
</script>
```

You might need to integrate to PHP & JS code into your application.